# get difference of two shape files

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, shapefile, shapely

I'm having two shape files which is contains polygons in it. I'm trying to find delta out of it. 
Trying to do this by following code but not working the way i expected.
Following is two shape files blue one is buffer shape file, I need to remove that buffer area which intersecting with blue buffer.i.e. need to get difference of geometry the same as **Qgis** **difference** **function**

[image]

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping, Polygon

green = fiona.open(
    "/home/gulve/manual_geo_ingestion/probe-data/images/r/shape_out/dissolved.shp")
blue = fiona.open(
    "/home/gulve/manual_geo_ingestion/probe-data/images/g/shape/shape.shp")

print([not shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])).is_empty for i, j in zip(list(blue), list(green))])

schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon',
          'properties': {}}
crs = {'init': u'epsg:3857'}

with fiona.open(
        '/home/gulve/manual_geo_ingestion/probe-data/images/r/shape_out/diff.shp', 'w',
        driver='ESRI Shapefile', crs=crs, schema=schema
) as write_shape:
    for geom in [shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for i, j in zip(list(blue), list(green))]:
        if not geom.empty:
            write_shape.write({'geometry': mapping((shape(geom))), 'properties': {}})
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Can you also provide the shapefiles?

Comment: sure how can i provide it

Comment: perhaps with a link to download?

Comment: okay will share in while

Comment: here is link for shape file   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BXbW9fmiFHyxIS2PZiSB2qWeaA5ZoVe-?usp=sharing

Comment: @JimJones i have shared the shape file link

Comment: I will add a query in a minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174419/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-abhijeet-gulve).

Answer (score 2):

After you imported the [shapefiles into PostgreSQL](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html#importing-data-into-a-database-with-db-manager), just execute this query:

```
CREATE TABLE not_intersects AS 
SELECT * FROM shape 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT shape.id
         FROM buffer,shape 
         WHERE ST_Intersects(buffer.geom,shape.geom));
```

This query will create a third table (called here `not_intersects`) containing the polygons that do not intersect between the two tables (shape files).

[image]

- The result is represented in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this with shapely functions

**Here's my code..**

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping, Polygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union

buffered_shape = fiona.open(
    "dissolved.shp", 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
color_shape = fiona.open(
    "shape.shp", 'r', encoding='UTF-8')

print([not shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])).is_empty for i, j in
       zip(list(color_shape), list(buffered_shape))])

outmulti = []
for pol in color_shape:
    green = shape(pol['geometry'])
    for pol2 in buffered_shape:
        red = shape(pol2['geometry'])
        if red.intersects(green):
            # If they intersect, create a new polygon that is
            # essentially pol minus the intersection
            intersect = green.intersection(red)
            nonoverlap = green.symmetric_difference(intersect)
            outmulti.append(nonoverlap)
        else:
            outmulti.append(green)

finalpol = unary_union(outmulti)

schema = {'geometry': 'MultiPolygon',
          'properties': {}}
crs = {'init': u'epsg:4326'}

with fiona.open(
        'shape_out/diff.shp', 'w',
        driver='ESRI Shapefile', crs=crs, schema=schema
) as write_shape:
    for geom in finalpol:
        # if not geom.empty:
        write_shape.write({'geometry': mapping(Polygon(shape(geom))), 'properties': {}})
```